# Codeship Build Error: error loading encrypted environment file, environment contains non-utf8 characters

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, environment-variables, codeship

I used jet to encrypt this.

however when loading the environmental variables, it fails:

```
Build Error: error loading encrypted environment file codeship.*********.env.encrypted: environment contains non-utf8 characters: K�okh�V����ڌ�--����
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when the key you used to encrypt the file with doesn't match the key stored on Codeship.

Could you re-download the keyfile from your projects General settings page and then re-encrypt the file and trigger a new build?

Comment: It turns out I was using the sample key file that only allowed it to run locally. I obtained the official keyfile from my project and it worked.